# Getting value of Response object in activiti bpnm xml

Tags: java, activiti

I am totally new to Activiti. There are very few resources available for Activiti.
What I want is: A process should go back to previous step if rejected. Now, this rejection comes in the form of a value to an attribute in the JSON object (Using Spring Boot).
How can I use this value in the activiti xml file.

More:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void updateMessage(@RequestBody WorkflowUpdateRequest request) {
    //Use request object
}
```

Incoming json: 
{
    "landId":"1001",
    "userName":"Admin",
    "requestApproved":"false"
}
How do I use this "requestApproved" value here??

```
<sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="usertask2" targetRef="endevent1">

 <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">
      <![CDATA[${requestApproved== 'true'}]]>
    </conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
```